# Ruby script to manage files

Tags: ruby, bash, file-management

I'm looking to write a script that can do the following:

I have a set of normal files such as "myFile.log" which I want to leave in their current state.

I would like to place all files that that are of type `myFile.log.year-month-day-hour` into a gzipped tar archive with separate sub-folders for each day.

Can anybody point me in the right direction as to how to get this done?

Comment: [whathaveyoutried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Iv just started this, just looking to be pointed in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do anything interesting with files in Ruby, you need to

```
require 'fileutils'
```

take a look in IRB at the methods you would then have available

```
1.9.3-p327 :001 > require 'fileutils'
 => true
1.9.3-p327 :002 > File.methods.sort - Object.methods
 => [:absolute_path, :atime, :basename, :binread, :binwrite, :blockdev?, :chardev?, :chmod, :chown, :copy_stream, :ctime, :delete, :directory?, :dirname, :executable?, :executable_real?, :exist?, :exists?, :expand_path, :extname, :file?, :fnmatch, :fnmatch?, :for_fd, :foreach, :ftype, :grpowned?, :identical?, :join, :lchmod, :lchown, :link, :lstat, :mtime, :open, :owned?, :path, :pipe, :pipe?, :popen, :read, :readable?, :readable_real?, :readlines, :readlink, :realdirpath, :realpath, :rename, :select, :setgid?, :setuid?, :size, :size?, :socket?, :split, :stat, :sticky?, :symlink, :symlink?, :sysopen, :truncate, :try_convert, :umask, :unlink, :utime, :world_readable?, :world_writable?, :writable?, :writable_real?, :write, :zero?]
1.9.3-p327 :007 > FileUtils.methods.sort - Object.methods
 => [:cd, :chdir, :chmod, :chmod_R, :chown, :chown_R, :cmp, :collect_method, :commands, :compare_file, :compare_stream, :copy, :copy_entry, :copy_file, :copy_stream, :cp, :cp_r, :getwd, :have_option?, :identical?, :install, :link, :ln, :ln_s, :ln_sf, :makedirs, :mkdir, :mkdir_p, :mkpath, :move, :mv, :options, :options_of, :private_module_function, :pwd, :remove, :remove_dir, :remove_entry, :remove_entry_secure, :remove_file, :rm, :rm_f, :rm_r, :rm_rf, :rmdir, :rmtree, :safe_unlink, :symlink, :touch, :uptodate?]
1.9.3-p327 :013 > Dir.methods.sort - Object.methods
 => [:[], :chdir, :chroot, :delete, :entries, :exist?, :exists?, :foreach, :getwd, :glob, :home, :mkdir, :open, :pwd, :rmdir, :unlink]
```

Start with e.g. `Dir.entries('/path')`, and use Ruby's array methods to work through the list, regular expressions to extract parts of the names, etc